# Nginx proxy_pass then try_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am setting up a Rails app with nginx in front.

What I want is first to check if the URL makes sense for Rails **then** serve content of the public folder.

I can't achieve this:

```
upstream extranet {
  server localhost:3000;
}

server {
  location / {
    try_files @extranet $uri;
    root /var/www/extranet/public;
  }

  location @extranet {
    proxy_pass          http://extranet;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
  }
}
```

I get: `*1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/"` error.

It seems like `try_files $uri @extranet;` works but in my case it feels safer to check the Rails app first because the public folder might change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`try_files` checks for the presence of a file on the local file system and cannot respond to the response code from a proxy.

Presumably, the proxy response with a 404 response if the remote page does not exist, which can be intercepted by an `error_page` statement.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass       http://extranet;
    proxy_set_header ...
    proxy_set_header ...
    proxy_set_header ...

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 = @fallback;
}
location @fallback {
    root /var/www/extranet/public;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for more.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!