# How to forward requests between docker containers from nginx reverse proxy to react routes in nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, react-router, nginx-reverse-proxy

I used the GitHub repo in the source below for setting up Dockerfiles and docker-compose and built on it.

How it works is that there is an Nginx reverse proxy that sends requests to the `client`(react) or `backend`(node js) depending on the URL.

This works fine for single-page React pages. I went and added multiple pages in a single react via `react-routes-dom`. I set it up like below and it works when I `npm start` the react code and access at `localhost:3000/path`.

```js
function Main() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={ComponentA} />
            <Route path='/path' exact component={ComponentB} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

The problem happens when I try to access it via the reverse proxy. The configuration is almost identical to the one here from the repo [default.conf](https://github.com/LukeMwila/multi-container-nginx-react-node-mongo/blob/master/nginx/configs/default.conf)

The problem happens when I try to access the other routes.
If I try to access the base path `localhost`. It works.
If I try to access the path `localhost/path`, it does not work.

Logs for accessing base `/`

```
client | 172.18.0.5 - - [06/Apr/2021:11:51:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36" "-"

nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2021:11:51:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Logs for accessing custom `/path`

```
nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2021:11:52:43 +0000] "GET /path HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36" "-"

client | 2021/04/06 11:52:43 [error] 31#31: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/path " failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.5, server: , request: "GET /path HTTP/1.0", host: "client"

client | 172.18.0.5 - - [06/Apr/2021:11:52:43 +0000] "GET /path HTTP/1.0" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I tried to modify the conf file following [React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx) , https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/nginx.html , [Nginx proxy_pass then try_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788437/nginx-proxy-pass-then-try-file) . They all don't work.

I tried to redirect all traffic to `/` to maybe help with the path, but I get an empty page.

```
location / {
    rewrite /(.*) / break;
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/LukeMwila/multi-container-nginx-react-node-mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-thinking it through and reading this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/8293176, I realized that I misunderstood the concept of routing in React.

What I did before was that I tried to apply the static re-routing within the `reverse proxy` conf file to the Nginx hosting react which was incorrect! It just brought me to another page.

I had to apply it to the Nginx hosting the React build itself. This way, the redirects are client-side.

I applied the `Catch-all` method proposed in the link referenced above and the links in the Question, and it worked nicely!

I hope this post can provide clarity to future readers.